# What are the top three recording studios of all time in terms of having sold the most songs?

Tags: chart-success

There are a lot of famous recording studios, but which of them can claim responsibility for producing output that has resulted in the most song sales? (That is, all sales including as single releases and album tracks.)

I know adding up all the track sales might take a while so I'm interested in answers suggesting likely candidates and why you think they would be on the list.

I'd include any studio a song would go through (including for both tracking and mixdown...) and let's make it a 'top 3' question in case #1 is too obvious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Abbey Road](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbey_Road_Studios) has got to be in the running for top spot.
The [list of artists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_artists_who_have_recorded_at_Abbey_Road_Studios) who have recorded there reads like a Hall of Fame, from Glenn Miller, The Beatles, through Pink Floyd, Michael Jackson, Stevie Wonder, to U2, Muse & Lady Gaga.
The [list of recordings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_recordings_made_at_Abbey_Road_Studios) is enough to bring a tear to the eye.
& that's without the [list of movie & game scores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_recordings_made_at_Abbey_Road_Studios) done there

It also has to have the only zebra [pedestrian] crossing in the world to have 'listed building' status ;-)

Comment: And the road sign is now painted on the wall as they got annoyed with having to replace it every couple of months...

Answer (score 4):

Far less known is RockField studios in Monmouth. However, their roster of artists is very impressive...

[Rockfield history](http://www.rockfieldmusicgroup.com/default.asp?contentID=548)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockfield_Studios)

> 1960’s
>
> The Interns, Love Sculpture, Amen Corner, Doc Thomas Band (Mott the Hoople)
>
> 1970’s
>
> Queen, Rush, Dave Edmunds, Ace, Black Sabbath, Prelude, Mike Oldfield, Hawkwind, Edwin Starr, Man, Del Shannon, Gary Shearston, Arthur Brown, City Boy, Roy Harper, Van der Graaf Generator, Motorhead, Carlene Carter
>
> 1980’s
>
> Simple Minds, Adam and the Ants, The Damned, Clannad, Echo and the Bunnymen, The Undertones, The Waterboys, Robert Plant, Icicle Works, Bauhaus, T’Pau, Age of Chance, Edie Brickel & the New Bohemians, That Petrol Emotion, Fields of the Nephilim, The Wonderstuff
>
> 1990’s
>
> Aztec Camera, The Stone Roses, The Pogues Hot House Flowers, Del Amitri, Big Country, XTC, Neds Atomic Dustbin, Annie Lennox, The Charlatans, 
>   Sepultura, Herbert Gronemeyer, Oasis, Ash, Black Grape, The Boo Radleys, The Wedding Present, 60’ Dolls, Cast, Super Furry Animals, Paul Weller, Menswear, Julian Lennon, The Bluetones, Manic Street Preachers, Gene, Beta Band, Teenage Fanclub, Toploader, Gaydad, Coldplay
>
> 2000’s
>
> New Order, Catatonia, Suede, Star Sailor, Supergrass, Coldplay, Manic street preachers, Joe Strummer, The Darkness, Morning Runner, Kasabian, Badly Drawn Boy, KT Tunstall, The Proclaimers, Paulo Nutini, Heaven and Hell, Nigel Kennedy, Simple Minds, The Delays, Bullet for my Valentine